# Max capacity of Memcache

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching, memcached, ehcache

I am using Memcache in my project for that I want some information but I am not getting these information on google . What is the total maximum capacity of Memcache and maximum size of the key and value that can be stored in memcache?

Comment: "The default maximum object size is 1MB. In memcached 1.4.2 and later, you can change the maximum size of an object using the -I command line option." https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.6-en/ha-memcached-faq.html#qandaitem-17-6-5-1-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the total maximum capacity of Memcache

As far as I can tell, it is limited only by the amount of memory available on all of the servers running `memcached` instances.

> ... the maximum size of the key

Up to 250 bytes: reference [the wiki](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands#Standard_Protocol).

> ... maximum size of a value.

This is implementation specific.  The `stats` command with the argument `settings` will give you a bunch of settings including a `item_size_max` setting which is the maximum size allowed for a given `memcached` instance.

Note that the value size is also limited by the amount of memory you have allowed an `memcached` instance to use.